# Java happens-before clarification and how to safely pass an object back and forth between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, happens-before

I would like to establish a simple "protocol" between two threads of using an arbitrary object, not specifically geared towards multi-threading, in a thread-safe manner. The protocol shall be that only ever one of the threads **owns** the object and only the owner may read/write the object. I read the information about *happens-before* [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility), but are not quite sure whether the discussion relates only to individual fields or to whole objects. Are the following two solutions correct for the "ownership protocol"?

1) Use of a BlockingQueue such that the object is passed over to the other thread through the queue.

2) The "arbitray object" is not so arbitrary anymore in that I introduce a

```
  volatile boolean ownedByThreadA;
```

with `ownedByThreadA` being `true` initially and Thread A is using the object. When done, Thread A writes `false` into `ownedByThreadA`. Thread B polls the variable similar to this

```
while (data.ownedByThreadA) {
  doOtherThings();
}
dealWith(data);
```

I am rather sure that (1) is a correct solution. I am not so sure for for (2). In particular for (2) I wonder if just one `volatile` suffices for a correct solution, given the "user protocol" is obeyed.

Comment: one volatile does not suffice. both ownedByThreadA and data need to be volatile.

Comment: I was rather interested whether more fields within `data` need volatile.

Comment: `while (data.ownedByThreadA) doOtherThings()` is a very poor design solution, leading directly to bullshit-code. Regarding to your question, it is possible to synchronize threads with only a set of volatile variables, without synchronized blocks or library solutions, but I strictly do not recommend doing so.

Comment: If you swap instances around between threads using blocking queues, you should be fine.  If only one thread at a time has access to the instance, you shouldn't need any other protections.  Simple really - once you queue off an instance, don't touch it again in that thread, (unless/until it's queued back again later).

Comment: @Alexei I don't see anything wrong with that approach and why it would be a poor design. Doing work asynchronously while waiting for a task to complete is rather common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is guaranteed that every write done by Thread A before `ownedByThreadA = false` must be visible to Thread B after it has seen `!ownedByThreadA`.

You also have to be careful how you update the `data` variable itself (if thread b changes it to something else and the member is not volatile itself you've a bug for example), but assuming that both threads work on the same instance you get correct behavior.

Comment: My idea is indeed that the variable called `data` itself is never changed. Consider it final. This is the clear and concise answer I was hoping for. Just to be sure: "every write done by Thread A" covers all writes to all data, not just all writes to data.ownedByThreadA? This distinction is also not clear in the javadocs I cited, which triggered this whole question.

Comment: @Harald Yep *all* writes that precede the write to `ownedByThreadA`. `x = 5;ownedByThreadA=false;y = 10`  - the other thread is guaranteed to see x == 5, but whether it sees the update to y or not is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need at particular moment of time only one thread *owns* and thus can read/write object, consider adding `synchronized` blocks to methods that are used to perform read and write data to it.

For example, let's imagine your object is a set of strings, saying "write" means "adding a string to the set", saying "read" means "getting the number of strings in a set".

```
public class SetHolder {

    private static Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void writeData(String data) {
        synchronized(set) {
            set.add(data);
        }
    }

    public int readData() {
        synchronized(set) {
            return set.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your solution with volatile flag: I would not recommend to use that, because the check `if (ownedByThreadA) {` and the code that should be executed makes nonatomic operation, which leads to possible race conditions, when the `ownedByThreadA` flag change its value, while this nonatomic operation is not yet finished.

If you really need to **transfer an object between two threads** or let the two threads exchange by some objects, consider using `Exchanger` class.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I know that I can pepper synchronized all over, but that my goal was to prevent this. Given the "owns protocol" I described, I don't understand your statement about the non-atomic operations. The whole point of my question is whether happens-before allows me to do such non-atomic operations if I use the volatile flag **and** obey the "owns protocol" as described - which exactly means that the flag is not changed while non-atomic operations are in progress.

Comment: JMM guarantees that volatile write happends-before volatile reads, but the data variable itself is not volatile and not immutable, so we cannot assume any visibility guarantees. Also, volatile read and write are not being reordered, so as far as I understand your idea, moving `ownedByThreadA` outside of data itself and changing its value **after** all operations with `data` is finished should give you the results you expect.

Comment: @Alexey If the data variable is changed by ThreadA (and it's not volatile) there's a problem (but then that sounds unlikely), but otherwise every write to data before `ownedByThreadA = false` *must* be visible to Thread B at that point in time.